# how to get total send balance of account in orbitcoin wallet?

Tags: php, balance

I want to see my account balance in wallet using console but when i use getbalance test its only show me total receive balance?

There is many account that i want to see total balance but i try listreceivedbyaccount test is show me received balance?

And I also try getreceivedbyaccount.

And I'm trying create a web wallet in php a web wallet for orbitcoin.

Please, anybody help me!

Comment: Is 'test' part of the command that you're running? What do you mean by 'total send balance?'

Comment: I mean i want to get balance of account name is test but when i use its only show me received balance not include send balance for example the account is received 0.1 orb and after sending 0.1 the current balance is 0 but the command is still show me 0.1 not current balance ??